# Como receber um SMS via Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sms

Tenho um sistema que usa o `framework` PHP Codeigniter e preciso receber SMS de um GPS desses de carro, que me dará as coordenadas do carro ao estilo do Google Maps e daí eu guardo no banco de dados coordenadas e *data*.

Existe alguma biblioteca, API ou lugar que eu possa olhar para me ajudar a desenvolver isso?

Comment: você já tentou alguma coisa? tem uma ideia do caminho que prefere seguir? se sim, poste para nós seu progresso. php não é meu forte, mas sua pergunta me parece muito ampla

Comment: Como você faz a escuta do número que irá receber o SMS? Utiliza algum serviço? Insira mais informações.